# Trouble connecting javascript code to html code

Tags: javascript, html, forms, calculator

I am creating a calculator and I have written the following code:

For javascript:

```
function calculate() {
'use strict';
 var total;
 var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
 var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
 var tax = document.getElementById('tax').value;
 var discount = document.getElementById('discount').value;
 total = quantity*price;
 tax /= 100;
 tax++;
 total *= tax;
 tax = tax/100;
 tax = tax+1;
 total = total*tax;
 total -= discount;
 document.getElementById('total').value = total;
 return false;
 }
 function init() {
 'use strict';
 var theForm = document.getElementById('theForm');
 theForm.onsubmit = calculate;
 }
 window.onload=init;
```

For html:

```
 <div><label for="quantity">Quantity</label><input type="number"
 name="quantity" id="quantity" value="1" min="1" required></div>

 <div><label for="price">Price Per Unit</label><input type="text"
 name="price" id="tax" value="1.00" required></div>

 <div><label for="tax">Tax Rate (%)</label><input type="text"
  name="tax" id="tax" value="0.0" required></div>

 <div><label for ="discount">Discount</label><input type="text"
  name="discount" id="discount" value="0.00" required></div>

 <div><label for="total">Total</label><input type="text" name="total"
 id="total" value="0.00"></div>

 <div><input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="submit"></div>
```

I have saved the files respectively as shopping.js and shopping.html but I don't know how to interconnect the code together so that when I click on the shopping.html and the browser opens, the calculator works properly.

I have tried to include the javascript code in the html code by using the script tags but it didn't work. I read some articles that said you have to save them in the same directory, but I did not understand that. I saved them on my desktop in a file called shopping and I need some assistance from here.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us the script tags you tried to use?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to move your <script> tags inside the <head> block of your HTML.

Comment: Where is the form tag?

Comment: I used <script></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/nLSXS/)**

The id for price was "tax" I think was just typo mistake. I changed also your input type sumbit to a button instead.

Code:

```
window.onload = function() { // this loads your script when the page loads
    function calculate() {  
   'use strict';
    var total = 0;

    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
    var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
    var tax = document.getElementById('tax').value;
    var discount = document.getElementById('discount').value;
    total = quantity * price;
    tax /= 100;
    tax++;
    total *= tax;
    tax = tax / 100;
    tax = tax + 1;
    total = total * tax;
    total -= discount;
    document.getElementById('total').value = total;
    return false;
    }
};
```

You can add this code to your page or call it by a external file, then you just need to put this in your html code `<script src="shopping.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. Put inside the `<head>` or `<body>` tags.

Comment: It is still not working. I don't know how to connect the html file to the javascript file.

Comment: @user1804697 - Check my answer again, now updated. The script should be inside the <body> of the page with, inside this tags: <script></script>

Comment: Yes it is working, but the problem is not that. I have a file on my desktop called workspace. Inside I saved it, shopping.html and shopping.js, the problem is I don't know how to connect them together

Comment: Ok, is it working now? If they are in the same directory check the last phrase of my answer, instructions are there. Let mo know if you run into trouble.

Comment: It is still not working! On my desktop I have a folder called workspace in which I saved the two files. Maybe I am not following when we say 'directory'..

Answer (score 2):

If they're in the same directory, you can call the js file in your HTML page like so:

```
<script src="shopping.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If it's in a folder you have to reflect that in the src line: foldername/filename

That's how to get an external js file into your HTML doc.  However, if you're putting your js code directly into script tags on the HTML doc and it's still not working, then there's an issue with the code.